# Lubuntu - Desktop Preferences error ¨Desktop Manager Not Active¨ 220.04

Tags: 22.04

using ubuntu 22.04.
cant get refresh rate correct only goes to 60MH. set to auto. now it wont open again.
can I do anything please?